# 64bit size types and Windows API

Tags: c++, winapi, 64-bit

How do you handle Windows API calls that take a size after converting to 64bit properly and safely?

For example:

From winsock

```
int send(
  _In_       SOCKET s,
  _In_ const char   *buf,
  _In_       int    len,
  _In_       int    flags
);
```

or

```
int MultiByteToWideChar(
  _In_      UINT   CodePage,
  _In_      DWORD  dwFlags,
  _In_      LPCSTR lpMultiByteStr,
  _In_      int    cbMultiByte,
  _Out_opt_ LPWSTR lpWideCharStr,
  _In_      int    cchWideChar
);
```

One would naturally call some_container::size() which is going to return a size_t. size_t when using 64bit a msvc compiler is an unsigned long long.

One could cast, but that isn't safe, since it is theoretically possible the container is a larger size than the boundry of an int.

One could check and then cast, but is that what people are really doing in practice? That's a lot of work on a large project that is being converted. Find and replace isn't going to work on that one.

What do you do? I have a feeling most people just ignore it, but that doesn't seem like the good thing to do. I like a nice build with no warnings.

Why don't they have 64 bit versions of these functions similar to how they have wide and multibyte versions of various functions?

Comment: You have to make an engineering decision. What are the odds that someone tries to send more than 2GB over a socket in your application? If the odds are zero, you might skip the test.

Comment: If there's no 64 bit version of the function then you have little choice but to cast and assume 2GB ought to be enough for anybody.

Comment: Write a wrapper function that deals with the case where size is >2Gb and performs the API call in a loop. Use this function even if the size is < 2Gb.  Put the static_cast(s), if required, inside the wrapper function.

Comment: In case of `send`, it makes no sense to specify a buffer that large, for optimal performance you should call `send` frequently and with small chunks (4..64KB).

Comment: `send()` will never be able to accept 2GB+ of data in one go. Networks can't handle data packets that large, and neither can the kernel that buffers outgoing data before transmitting it. Any noone in their right mind would ever try to call `MultiByteToWideChar()` with a block of text that has over 2billion ANSI characters in it in one go, which would require 2GB of input memory and 4GB of output memory. These aren't just technical limitations, they are logical ones, too. So there is no need to support 64bit sizes when they will not be utilized to their fullest extent to begin with